# Creating a bundle to publish an Android app

Tags: android, google-play, android-app-bundle

While trying to build and then upload a bundle to publish an Android app, I have the following issue.

In the Android Studio menu, I choose:

```
Build -> Generate Signed Bundle / APK...
```

I expect to see (at the end) a file called *app-release.aab* created in the directory:

```
/Users/me/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApp/app/release:
```

But I do not see it, I assume that for some reason it is not created.

I have a question, concerning the way I do.
Am I supposed to use a different upload key for each application I create?

If the answer to the question above is NO; what am I missing?

Comment: I hope you checked all possible available solutions. In my case, issue was, release folder and .jks file both are on different drive. So i put my jks in my source project and then it works.

Comment: My .jks file is not in the project folder but I used it before for another app and it was not in the project folder either at that time, but it worked. It is on the same disk anyway.

Comment: There might your .jks fine. you should try this solution once. It may helps you also. Also check your info logs. There is possibility to get proper reason for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you build signed bundle like this

```
Build -> Generate Signed Bundle / APK...
```

Android Studio must notify you about successful build with this notification in bottom-right corner of screen:
[image]

Once you click on `locate` word in this notification, you will be redirected to the real directory where bundle created is.

If you can't see this notification, maybe your build was failed? Are you sure build is success? Are you sure you build a release version, not debug?

Comment: @Ilin Pavel. For some reason that I totally ignore, it just worked after I read your answer. I was only lucky. Maybe thanks to you :)

Comment: I had closed Android Studio in the meanwhile.